# How to generate a number of Solana addresses

Tags: keypair

I would like to generate a number of Solana addresses and store them in a database. I plan to use them to display and receive payments. I don't need to verify (I only need to display a receiving address).

I tried a command line key generator - `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` and then tried to import it into a Phantom wallet and got a "wrong format" error.

Comment: Solved(pretty much). I installed Solana cli and have to say I am really impressed. The only thing left is to create multiple addresses and so far I only can see one? That's if I'm undertanding addresses correctly. I'm moving over from Bitcoin where the recommended practice has been to use a new address for each transaction. My goal (if that is correct is to generate a list of addresses) and air gap them.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using web3.js for this:

```
import { Keypair } from '@solana/web3.js';

for (let i = 0; i < NUM_TO_GENERATE; i++){
    const kp = Keypair.generate();
    console.log(kp.secretKey);
    console.log(kp.publicKey.toBase58());
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I went with Solana cli.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep generating addresses with the Solana CLI's `solana-keygen`, same as the first keypair you created, ie:

```
$ solana-keygen new -o FILENAME.json --no-bip39-passphrase
```

Feel free to do that on a loop to create all the keypairs you want, ie:

```
for i in {0..3}
do
  solana-keygen new -o keypair${i}.json --no-bip39-passphrase
done
```

Comment: The first code ("solana-keygen new -o FILENAME.json --no-bip39-passphrase") creates new seed phrase each time. The second does the same.

Comment: Can I get just the addresses saved to a file (while also saving the new json file as it already does)?

Comment: And I'm confused about the seed phrase. Isn't that used by elliptical curve? If so, could I generate a list from it? Is that only possible from Web3.js or can I also do that from the cli?